# Solving the "No package 'json' found" error

Tags: macos, configure

I'm on Mac OS X Mountain Lion and a newbie to autotools and other GNU build tools. I'm trying to build a custom version of json-c to use with a a C project ([axis2/c](http://axis.apache.org/axis2/c/core/)). After running the auto tools, and I run the configure command I get a failure with this output:

```
checking whether to use JSON... yes
checking for JSON... no
configure: error: Package requirements (json) were not met:

No package 'json' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables JSON_CFLAGS
and JSON_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

If I install json-c from macports, configure runs properly. Unfortunately, the project needs a later version of json-c, than what is available in macports (even though this is successful in the configure stage, it later results in a compilation error).

When I install this manually from source, I see that the libs are there in /usr/local/lib and header files in /usr/local/include/json-c. After removing any json-c files that came from macports, I tried copying these repective to the locations in /opt/local/lib and /opt/local/include/json-c but it still resulted in the same package not found error.

What does macports do differently that the package is 'found' when you run configure? Can I replicate the same when I manually install json-c from source?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Macports creates a .pc file with under /opt/local/pkgconfig/. In this case it was json.pc. I edited that to point to the locations in /usr/local and the configure found and used the package I manually built from source.